# Stop paperclip from cropping and resizing before other parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using Paperclip to store my image, and I want to create a cropped/rotated image as a thumbnail. Here is the PROPER command that Paperclip should be running:

```
convert [file].jpg -gravity center -distort SRT -30 -quality 100 -antialias -flatten -background white -unsharp 0.3x0.3+5+0 -crop 433x433+69+88 +repage -resize "300x300>" [file].jpg
```

This produces the result I want. I've tested it directly on my pc having installed imagemagick. However looking at the logs on my server, the order of these arguments is different. Paperclip wants to a) Put the `-resize "300x300>"` command FIRST, THEN puts `-crop 433x433+69+88` SECOND, and THEN put the rest of the arguments afterwards. This changes the look of the final image! Not what I want. Here's what it outputs in the logs:

```
convert [file].jpg -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" -crop 433x433+69+88 +repage -gravity center -distort SRT -30 -quality 100 -antialias -flatten -background white -unsharp 0.3x0.3+5+0 [file].jpg
```

...and here's my config in my model:

**Wine.rb**

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {
                    :thumb => {
                    :geometry => "300x300>",
                    :format => :jpg,
                    :processors => [:cropper, :recursive_thumbnail],
                    :thumbnail => :croppable
                    },
                    :general => ["150x375", :jpg],
                    :show => ["x425", :jpg],
                    :croppable => ["1200x1200>", :jpg]
        },
        :url  => "/assets/wines/:style/:wine_name",
        :path => ":rails_root/public:url",
        :default_url => ":wine_default",
        :default_path => ":rails_root/public:wine_default",
        :default_style => :show,
        :convert_options => {
            :thumb => '-gravity center -distort SRT -30',
            :croppable => '-gravity center -extent 1200x1200',
            :general => '-gravity center -extent 150x375 -quality 95',
            :all => '-quality 100 -antialias -flatten -background white -unsharp 0.3x0.3+5+0'
        },
        :processors => [:thumbnail, :compression]
```

Basically it runs convert.exe in this order: [:geometry][:transformations][:convert_options].

How do I get things in the order I want?

**recursive_thumbnail.rb** -- for running the :thumb thumbnail generation off of :croppable and not the original file (because of horizontal padding issues when cropping)

```
module Paperclip
    class RecursiveThumbnail < Thumbnail
    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
        super Paperclip.io_adapters.for(attachment.styles[options[:thumbnail] || :original]), options, attachment
    end
    end
end
```

**cropper.rb**

```
module Paperclip
    class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
        if crop_command
        super.join(' ').sub(/ -crop \S+/, '').split(' ') + crop_command
        else
        super
        end
    end

    def crop_command
        target = @attachment.instance
        if target.cropping?
        ["+repage", "-crop", "#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}", "+repage"]
        end
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: Wish I could help, but I could only recommend using standard Paperclip functions for this kind of thing :) If you'd like me to give you some ideas, I can do an answer?

Comment: Sure, whatever helps, helps. I could even do a custom-rolled processor that would override Paperclip's default procedure for generating the thumbnail, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating my own paperclip processor, but I ran into issues. My processor was overriding the cropper.rb processor as they both tried to use the same method within the Thumbnail processor; so I could move the resize command to the end of the arguments list but the crop argument was nowhere to be found. I couldn't figure out how to include the cropper processor inside of my custom processor, and the whole thing just seemed like a mess and it wasn't working.

No answer found. I ended up switching to Carrierwave and encountering another set of problems which I've finally arrived at a solution for. Too bad Carrierwave doesn't log the processing of images, but that's a small price to pay.

[Carrierwave RMagick not removing transparency in convert to jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625066/carrierwave-rmagick-not-removing-transparency-in-convert-to-jpg)
[Carrierwave +repage option not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626679/carrierwave-repage-option-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and realized I couldn't change the order of the cropping and resizing. But I did manage to do a small hack that allowed me to get the results I wanted. I created another image attachment on the model.

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :cropped_image, {:styles => :original => '1920x1680>', :processors => [:cropper]}
```

Which will only crop the image with the original size. Then the other image will be:

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :image, {:styles => IMAGE_STYLES, :processors => [:thumbnail]}
```

That one will have all your different size thumbnails and will do all the resizing. So after it crops, I do something like this:

```
self.image = self.cropped_image
self.save
```

Not the most ideal way but I got it to do what I wanted without sacrificing too much performance.